# JavaScript function not found on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Very simple minimal jsfiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/a9f2j4xo/

Clicking the button should invoke the `Bla()` function.

When I click the button the console says

```
ReferenceError: Bla is not defined.
```

Who or what is malfunctioning here, jsfiddle or my brain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to wrap the function script inside **`<head>`** . Otherwise your script is not invoked.

Change the settings as

```
LOAD TYPE - Wrap in <Head>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/76n5w9zr/)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something weird. Because on putting it inside script tag it is working. See js fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/a9f2j4xo/

```
<button onclick='Bla()'>
Test
</button>
<script>
function Bla()
{
    alert('yes'); 
}
</script>
```